# Should [nodeapi] be removed or re-tagged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The description of the tag [nodeapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nodeapi) states:

> hook_nodeapi() is the hook that on [Drupal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal) 6, and previous versions, acts on nodes.

So the tag is meant for [drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal).

However, it is mostly used for [Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js) questions and API design in Node.js. 
In some questions, it's even used as a replacement for [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js).

[image: Related Tags]

What's the best way to deal with this?

Comment: I'd suggest renaming to [tag:drupal-node-hook] and then review the 58 questions and remove it from those relating to [tag:node.js] etc.

Comment: Tag cleaned up - there's only drupal questions left. I'll leave it to a mod to rename the tag

Comment: @Zoe "I'll leave it to a mod to rename the tag" - Seems like you don't have any excuses left now :^)

Comment: Indeed ^^ Merged the tags, though it does seem that I erased the tag wiki in the process. Whoops

Comment: @Zoe Merging a tag into another "orphans" the tag wiki of the tag you merged. Therefore, if the tag you're merging with the attempt to eliminate has a better wiki than the tag you're merging it *into*, it's best to update the tag wiki of the final tag first, before doing the merge. But if you forget, all hope is not lost. The "orphaned" tag wikis can be accessed here: https://stackoverflow.com/admin/orphan-wikis. Unfortunately, like most mod tools, the UI is... not great.

Comment: @CodyGray Yikes, not great is an understatement. The tab crashed